# VMware Horizon View Client Dual Monitors

Tags: view, client, vmware, google-chrome-os, horizon

I am trying to get the Horizon View Client to work with dual monitors on a Chrome Box. There are no options in the Horizon View Client to turn on dual monitors, only to change the screen resolution. I am struggling to find any sources online about the issue as well. I am running VMware 4.7 which seems to be the newest on Chrome OS. Has anyone been able to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

With the multiple monitor feature, you can extend a remote desktop to one external monitor.

About this task
To enable the multiple monitor feature for Horizon Client, you install a helper extension and enable Unified Desktop Mode on your Chromebook.

You must install the helper extension to make the remote desktop window display correctly on an external monitor when the Chromebook display and the external display have different width-to-length ratios.

Procedure
Log in to your Chromebook.
Download and install the VMware Horizon Client Helper extension from the Chrome Web Store.
Open a browser window on your Chromebook and type chrome://flags in the URL bar.
Scroll down to Unified desktop mode and tap Enable.
Tap Restart Now to restart your Chromebook and make the change take effect.
What to do next
After your Chromebook restarts, you can open the Chromebook Settings and tap Display settings to configure Unified Desktop display options.

To extend a remote desktop window to the external monitor, tap the Maximize button. You can tap the Restore button to make the remote desktop window go back to the Chromebook monitor.